# Best equalizer for a perfect CSI

Tags: digital-communications, estimation, equalization, equalizer

Assuming a MIMO system and a perfect CSI (the channel matrix is known), what can be the best equalizer? ZF or others?

Comment: MMSE is superior to ZF. Keep in mind that in MIMO the specific form of the equalizer depends on the space-time code used.

Comment: @MBaz That's OK. Could you please post a full answer to make the question solved.